# mysql.exe doesn't run on windows machine

Tags: mysql, windows

I can't open mysql.exe that is included with XAMPP. If I click the file, it will open cmd for a blink and disappeared. I tried to run it as administrator, nothing happened. I also try to use mysql.exe included with WAMP, the result is the same. The tutorial I follow [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxe6qev-bno&t=1082s) can open it.

[Tutorial Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTvNJ.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: mysql has an error log which describes the error. If you have mupltile servers, you need to give every instance its own ports

Comment: unfortunately, XAMPP doesn't give me any error log. The port used is 3306.

Comment: xampp has a gui, mysql.exe is a shell command that needs parametrs like host user and sometimes even more try `mysql --user=user_name --password db_name` user name is root password depends, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html  also read here https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html  i know that xampp has phpmyadmin on board

Comment: Btw, you have mariadb, not mysql. No, the two are not the same.